# TypeScript error - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type

Tags: typescript

got this error on my typings.d.ts. file

error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'module' must have type 'NodeModule', but here has type '{id:string}'.

```
declare var module: {
  id: string;
};

declare module '*';
declare module 'clappr';
declare module 'c3';
declare module 'd3';
```

why ? anyway to solve it ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago...

To me, updating an Angular app, the error at ng serve was:

"ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(117,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'module' must be of type '{ id: string; }', but here has type 'NodeModule'"

So I go to node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(117,13) and MANUALLY do this:

```
//declare var module: NodeModule;    <---- old text
declare var module: { id: string; };   <--- new text
```

Now it compile... But I'm going to test the app...

ng -v:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.8
@schematics/angular          0.6.8
@schematics/update           0.6.8
rxjs                         6.2.1
typescript                   2.7.2
```

and my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "@ngui/map": "^0.18.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.117",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: My app is working, but with a error in a google-maps component I think unrelated to the error of the question...